# Microsoft Office, Exchange, Calendar, Snooze issue, Resending Invitation

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar, messages

So here is a weird bug, I've created a Reoccurring Meeting in OSX Outlook 2011 but every time I hit snooze using OSX Notifications the Meeting Invite is sent out again with the same time. Why is this happening?

Comment: I also get this issue - did you ever find out why it's happening?

Comment: wish I could help, I just delete the meeting and start a new if needed. Post back if you find something

Comment: I also see this behaviour in Mac Calendar.

Comment: unfortunately this behavior seems to pretty common, regardless of which app you use to connect to an Exchange account (I've tried with mail.app, Outlook 2011 and Outlook 15.9). What's even worse, when you dismiss the reminder (instead of snoozing it) you might end up sending meeting cancelations.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm that this is a common behavior in Mac Outlook or Calendar. It's working as expected.

> Why is this happening?

It's a incompatibility issue with your Exchange Server. e.g. a outdated MS Exchange server version. Somehow your Mac Outlook changes are ignored or not being synced. What Exchange Server version do you use? Also make sure that you are running the latest Mac Outlook Version.

The best way is to get in touch with your ISP or Server Administrator, so he/she could take a look at the debug logfiles.